# LG internal GPS Timestamp is wrong

Tags: java-me, timestamp, gps, lg

I am developing a J2ME GPS tracking software. I am testing it on LG Touch Screen and i get the wrong timestamp. it's 10 years and 5 days different than the current date(now it show 2000 not 2010). I have done some search and see some people say there's some bug in LG GPS timestamp.

Can anyone give me some advice on the work around for this? Advice and suggestion are much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The GPS epoche is Jan 6, 1980. The UTC epoch is Jan 1, 1970. Most phones use GPS and most PCs use pseudo-UTC. I use the prefix pseudo to say that UTC time accounts for leap seconds that are currently 16 different than the straight conversion of GPS to UTC (as of Oct 2012). PCs are usually updated from internet sources (so PC are lucky to be able to opt out of this 16 secs issue).

Comment: I guess I could have also stated - Standard storage of GPS and UTC are either millisecs or secs since the respective GPS or UTC epoch. The epochs are tied to GMT (Greenwich Mean Time). In order to convert these times, you need to know your local time zone (and possibly if daylight savings time is in effect).

Answer (score 0):

Time = Unix timestamp format. I added 64800 second to the time so it would be converted to Mountain Standard Time.

```
*timestamp
24 * 60 * 60

.getTime()//milliseconds
24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

private DateField dateField1;
///////////////////////

dateField1= new DateField("Date:", DateField.DATE);
f.append(dateField1);

Date d = new Date();
dateField1.setDate(d);

String TimeSeg = String.valueOf(((dateField1.getDate().getTime()/1000)+64800));
```